# How to fetch salesforce dx output json when error happens

Tags: json, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am writing a node js program to execute salesforce dx cli commands. And I am using --json option to fetch the data.

When the result is successful, it works perfectly fine. But when error happens, the stderr output is not a mere json. It looks like this:

[image]

So after the json file, there is one extra line:

> !    This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX
>   project.

The first thing I can think of is to use javascript substr function. As below:

```
    let errObj = JSON.parse(stderr.substr(0, stderr.indexOf('}') + 1));
    console.log('Error message is: ' + errObj.message);
```

However, end with "}" doesn't seem to be very promising since it might still contain sub object. and if I use "!" as the delimiter, it seems to be different on different platforms and in macOs it seems to be a small triangle which doesn't seem to be a valid character.

Any thoughts about how should I fetch the correct json data?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the *testcmd* directory in which you're running this command contains a *sfdx-project.json* file?

That should be present at the root of a salesforceDX project for the CLI to identify a SalesforceDX project.

Salesforce recommends using [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) which is a JSON parser for shell json outputs.

Using --json parameter and JQ to parse it you can even make a CSV of errorLogs and save it, I am currently doing it without no issues with something like this:

```
sfdx force:source:push --json -u $SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS 3>&1 1>&2- 2>&3-)| jq -r '.result | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' >logs.csv 2>/dev/null || :
```

You could customize it anyway you want, and check your JQ syntax at http://jqplay.org/